# "More than one"

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

> When **more than one** stands alone, it usually takes a singular verb, but
> it may take a plural verb if the notion of **multiplicity** predominates:
>
> *The operating rooms are all in good order. **More than one** is (or **are**)
> equipped with the latest imaging technology.*
>
> When **more than one** is followed by of and a plural noun, the verb is
> plural: *More than one of the paintings **were** stolen*.

What does **multiplicity** exactly mean here?

Secondly, I cannot check on Ngrams, but feel the singular is right in the second example

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using the American Heritage dictionary, if you then follow on to the "[one](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=O5084000)" section there is a much larger discussion of the issue. There seems to be no clear answer for all cases, and there seems to be disagreement in many cases.

If the thing we are talking about is clearly singular then we can easily use the singular, and viceversa. That's what multiplicity means, if you have several, then use the plural.