# Should "more than one" be followed by plural, or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What should "more than one" be followed by?

E.g., "more than one word is suitable", or "more than one words are suitable"?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/15w3im6/should_more_than_one_be_followed_by_plural_or/

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["More than one"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/293733/more-than-one)

Answer (score 1):

*More than one* is followed by a singular.

The iWeb corpus finds only 6 examples of "more than one [plural noun]", against 99599 for just the first 100 nouns in the pattern "more than one [singular noun]". It has 10555 instances of "more than one person", but zero instances of "more than one people".